# how to delete a dataframe wirth BigR?

Tags: biginsights, bigr

I have a dataframe created as such (from the BigR tutorials):

```
airfile <- system.file("extdata", "airline.zip", package="bigr")
airfile <- unzip(airfile, exdir = tempdir())
airR <- read.csv(airfile, stringsAsFactors=F)

# Upload the data to the BigInsights server. This may take 15-20 seconds
air <- as.bigr.frame(airR)
air <- bigr.persist(air, dataSource="DEL",
                         dataPath="/user/bigr/examples/airline_demo.csv",
                         header=T, delimiter=",", useMapReduce=F)
```

Is it possible to delete the dataframe using the bigr library?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I wasn't looking in the right place.  I was looking for an operation on the dataset, but a file system operation is required:

```
bigr.rmfs("/user/bigr/examples/airline_demo.csv", force = F, recursive = T)
```